# How to mark date in monthCalendar?

Tags: c#

How I can paint an arbitrary day with red color and bold font, and some other day in green color?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beyond the capabilities of the standard WinForm control. But you might want to look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/MonthCalendar.aspx)  or several other open source replacements.

To set some specifc days to bold you could use:

```
// Add dates to BoldedDates array.
        this.monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = new System.DateTime[] {
                                    new System.DateTime(2002, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    new System.DateTime(2002, 4, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    new System.DateTime(2002, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    new System.DateTime(2002, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    new System.DateTime(2002, 12, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    new System.DateTime(2002, 12, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0)};
```

You can also use the `SelectionRange` property of the control to mark a range of adjacent days like this:

```
// Select the week using SetSelectionRange ().
         this.monthCalendar1.SetSelectionRange (
               new System.DateTime(2002, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0),
               new System.DateTime(2002, 4, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```

But this feature is buggy and only works with disabled visual styles. See MSDN for more details.

Comment: OK, so how i can only mark with bold font the 01/01/2009 and 05/01/2009 date's ? monthCalendar1.BoldedDates........ How ?